# React Native flexbox align

Tags: react-native, flexbox

[image]Im trying to get a very simple layout in react-native flexbox.

Im just trying to have a scrollview of images.
Two side by side images per row with some padding.

Like a grid of sorts but only two images per line. Nicely spaced.

How would I achieve this in flex box.

right now its just rendering the images all to the left.

```
   scrollView: {
flex:0.5,
flexDirection: 'column'
  },
 row: {
flex:0.5,
flexDirection: 'column',
alignItems: 'center',
justifyContent: 'flex-start'
 }
```

Im not too familiar with it, so I just put in what intuitively felt correct.  But its obviously not working at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this by calculating the width of the device using Dimensions, then using that as the width for the items. Check out [this](https://rnplay.org/apps/wXeffA) example I set up.

https://rnplay.org/apps/wXeffA

[image]

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');
var {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Dimensions,
  ScrollView
} = React;

var width = Dimensions.get('window').width - 20
var circles = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

var SampleApp = React.createClass({

  render() {

    let Circles = circles.map((c, i) => {
    return <View key={ i } style={ styles.cContainer }><View style={ styles.c }></View></View>
    })

    return (
      <View style={{ flex:1 }}>
        <ScrollView style={{ flex:1 }}>
         <View style={ styles.container }>{ Circles }</View>
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    );
  }
});

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop:60,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    flexWrap: 'wrap'
  },
  cContainer: {
    margin: 10,
    height:width / 2 - 10,
    width: width / 2 - 10
  },
  c: {
    backgroundColor: '#ededed',
    borderRadius: width / 4,
    flex:1
  }

});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('SampleApp', () => SampleApp);
```

Comment: How would I add centered text under each circle??  RIght now I end up with Text on left, circle on right, per box

Comment: Check out the example, I've added centered text.

Answer (score 0):

use `flexDirection: 'row'`, that will align the `images` inside of the view horizontally, put 2 of each inside of their own little `view` container

its going to looks something like this inside of the scrollview

```
    <ScrollView>
        <View >
           <Image />
           <Image />
        </View>
        <View>
           <Image />
           <Image />
        </View>
        //etc...
    </ScrollView>
```

edit: more indepth example

```
    <View style={[styles.buttonBar, {borderWidth: 1, backgroundColor: '#EBEEF7',}]}>
        <TouchableHighlight style={styles.centerButton} onPress={()=> this.composeEmail()}>
            <Text>Compose</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
        <TouchableHighlight style={styles.centerButton} onPress={()=> this.removeMessage()}>
            <Text>Delete</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
        <TouchableHighlight style={styles.centerButton}>
            <Text>untrash</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
    </View>
```

styles:

```
buttonBar: {
    flex: .1,
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
    alignItems: 'center',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    padding: 5,
},

centerButton: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    },
```

Comment: How would I iterate that from an array. Normally modulo ....but how to do that with a map?

Comment: What do you mean Modulo?

Comment: The modulo operation.  Usually used to render a particular amount of things and then render a divider and then repeat.  So in this case used to render 2 images per row.  But i'm using a map, and react native so I can't do that.  Or can I just build the jsx inside a function that uses modulo and build my jsx like that to insert?

Comment: I am used to it being called modulus :) Create another question, the one you are asking is different from this post, mark mine as correct. And I will answer the new question when you post it. I can't post another answer here.